# Can't get stacktrace with `eval` when there is an error in the expression

Tags: ruby, eval

I'm using `eval` on large blocks of code with this rescue block:

```
rescue => e
  logger.error e.message
  e.backtrace.each { |line| logger.error line }
end
```

The rescue block does not provide line number, etc. for the exception. I just get this:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

which is not very helpful when there is a lot of code to evaluate. I tried various things such as:

```
eval(exp, binding, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

but they do not provide any additional information on the line number of where the error is.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help.  This answer is sort of based on details from [this article](http://cubus.ro/en/blog/6-ruby-eval-stacktrace-position-information). Assuming that you have expression to be evaluated in `exp` variable, I adjust the line number value passed as 3rd parameter to `String#module_eval`.

```
begin
exp = <<EOL
  a = nil
  a + 10
EOL
String.module_eval(exp,__FILE__, __LINE__ - 1 - exp.split("\n").size )
rescue Exception => e
  puts e
  puts e.backtrace
end
```

The output of above program:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
E:/hello.rb:4:in `<main>'
E:/hello.rb:6:in `module_eval'
E:/hello.rb:6:in `<main>'
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: This didn't give me much details of where the error is in the variable exp.  Here's part of my exp variable
ar = [{"source"=>"manual", "averageweight"=>"74.3", "maxweight"=>"86.2", "averageweightlastweek"=>"73.5", "weightdiff"=>"-0.8", "totalcount"=>"8"}] ; max_weights = [{"source"=>"manual", "timestamp"=>"2015-11-12 04:39:00", "maxweight"=>"86.2"}] ; min_weights = [{"source"=>"manual", "timestamp"=>"2015-10-23 21:52:00", "minweight"=>"65.8"}, {"source"=>"manual", "timestamp"=>"2015-11-06 18:37:00", "minweight"=>"65.8"}] ; time_zone = ' Pacific Time (US & Canada) '.strip ;